# How to make spinner return an id in android?

Tags: android, spinner

I have made a `Spinner` in Android:

```
category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ev_category);
category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
this, R.array.category_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
category.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The resource for the spinner is:

```
<string name="category">Choose a category</string>
<string-array name="category_list">
<item>Food</item>
<item>Art And Performance</item>
<item>Classes</item>
<item>Others</item>
</string-array>
```

See, I am getting my selected `Spinner` text by implementing the following method. It is returning my selected item text in my `Spinner`.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    ev_category=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
}
```

I want the below functionality. If the first item in my spinner is selected I want to get the values as "1" and if the next item in spinner is selected i want to get value as "2".
How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
View view, int pos, long id) {
```

`pos` here is position isn't it?, add 1 to it, if it returns 0 for first item.

if you want string, then convert integer to string using `Integer.toString()`

Comment: Ok i gt it correct nw.. How to enable multiple selection for the same spinner and also how to get the values as 1,2 if i selected the first two category items.?

Comment: spinners are designed to select only 1 item, so if you want to use multiple selections, you need to use different approach.

Answer (score 0):

in any method u can call   `getItemPosition  = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();`
and you can use (switch)  it will return you 0, 1, 2.